# Pass newline character as argument to function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use a function to build a string based on a separator that is passed in as an argument. One of the separators is the `\n` character, passing in the newline character as an argument isn't outputting what I expected.

```
let concat = function(a, b, sep) {
  return a + sep + b;
};

concat('Hello', 'World', '\n'); // Outputs 'Hello\nWorld'
```

> #### Desired output:
>
> Hello
>   World

How can I implement this so that I get my output string respecting the newline character escape notation instead of treating it as the string `'\n'`?

Comment: Where do you want the desired output - in the console or in the browser?

Comment: @cezar This is for a Node.js app, so console.

Comment: Try to print it, you'll see it works. I don't know js, but if it's like python, values have different representations depending on if they're evaluated in the shell and displayed or explicitly printed

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That was exactly it, I wasn't wrapping this in a `console.log()` and was just observing the output naively expecting the results to properly print when its actually just returning the constructed value.

Comment: then you can answer your own question :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to print it (using `console.log()` as you mentioned), you'll see it works.

I checked it online to avoid been downvoted :) I generated some lame pre-formatted HTML to see if linefeed worked.

```
let concat = function(a, b, sep) {
  return a + sep + b;
};

document.writeln(concat('<PRE>Hello', 'World</PRE>', '\n'));
```

outputs

```
Hello
World
```

in the document

I don't know js, but if it's like python, values have different representations depending on if they're evaluated in the shell (or debugger) and displayed or explicitly printed. Can be frustrating sometimes.

Answer (score 5):

Node.js has constant for that: `EOL`:

```
var eol = require('os').EOL;

let concat = function(a, b, sep) {
  return a + sep + b;
};

concat('Hello', 'World', eol);
```

http://nodejs.org/api/os.html#os_os_eol